# What is the best way to transfer 4tb image from windows to centos?

Tags: upload

My windows server has 4tb image files, images are scattered in folders by year(10 years), i want to transfer these images to centos. Is there a tool that can upload multiple(not one by one in queue), and retry upload when fail?

Comment: The best way depends, you can copy over the network (by means of exporting a  network share to the other server, or plethora of other networking protocols like rsync, ftp, scp etc.) copy the data to a portable drive and connect that to the new server, or remove the hard disks from the existing server and (temporarily) install them in the new

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have network access between both machines, use [RSYNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync). There is a version for Windows as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a FTP server (ProFTPd, Pure-FTPd) on your CentOS machine. There are FTP clients for Windows which support auto retry on failure. FTP clients which support auto retry: Flash FXP, Cute FTP of Leech FTP.